# How to correctly pass data between ViewModel and EditText if the EditText was inflated through AndroidView

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-jetpack-compose

So, I am using Compose for my Android app and I **need** to replace the Compose implementation of TextField with EditText. As the title says, I am using AndroidView to do that. The problem is that I can't figure out how to correctly pass data(text) between EditText and my ViewModel. I want to be able to set my ViewModel text variable through EditText, and in reverse I need to be able to set the text in EditText through ViewModel. The issue with the approaches I've tried is that either I can't change the text from ViewModel or the text starts being sent cyclically back and forth between ViewModel and EditText, resulting in a glitched out text field. My current appoach is this:

My text variable in ViewModel is set like this:

```
var searchText by mutableStateOf("")
    private set
```

Also, in my ViewModel I have a method that sets this variable to a parameter that is passed through to it:

```
fun onSearchTextChange(s: String) {
        if (s != searchText) {
            searchText = s
            // Some other stuff that I do in this method
        }
    }
```

I pass both the variable and the method to my EditText like so:

```
AndroidView(
    factory = { context ->
        EditText(context)
            .apply {
                //Text handling
                addTextChangedListener(MyTextWatcher(this) { text ->
                    onSearchTextChange(text)
                })

            }
        },
    update = { editText ->
         if (editText.text.toString() != searchText) {
             //editText.setText(searchText)  If I uncomment this then the text gets sent cyclically between EditText and ViewModel, which can only be solved by force closing the app
         }
    }
)
```

I have found some answers to similar questions that suggest removing the TextWatcher before changing text and adding it back afterwards. Therefore I have created a custom TextWatcher:

```
class MyTextWatcher(private val editText: EditText, private val onValueChange: (String) -> Unit) :TextWatcher {
    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        editText.addTextChangedListener(this)
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        if (editText.text.toString() != s.toString()) {
            editText.setText(s.toString())
        }
    }

    override fun afterTextChanged(e: Editable) {
        if (editText.text.toString() != e.toString()) {
            editText.removeTextChangedListener(this)
        }

        onValueChange(e.toString())
    }
}
```

However this doesn't allow me to change the text in the field by typing. I can only change it by other means. Like a button that calls the ViewModel method to change text.